# ¿Cómo hago para solucionar "El almacenamiento de configuración phpMyAdmin no está completamente configurado"?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Cuando inicio phpmyadmin me sale un error como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado solucionarlo dándole click en "Averigüe por qué" y luego le doy donde dice "Cree" pero aún así no se me ha solucionado el problema.

Comment: por favor escribe tu error en formato texto y quita la imagen para que se entienda mejor

Comment: te acabo de poner una solución

Comment: Pon el problema en el título, y el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Por otra parte, @JavierG.Raya : debe ser el OP quien transcriba el error.

Comment: vale muchas gracias, era para que se viera mejor

Comment: @JuanCas te ha servido mi respuesta

Comment: @JuanCas si te ha funcionado dale la fecha hacia arriba para que futuros usuarios sepan que funciona

Answer (score -1, accepted):

si estás manejando XAMPP (SOLUCIÓN RÁPIDA)

debes primero ir a Cuentas de usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y definir una contraseña para todos los usuarios para ello nos vamos a

Editar privilegios > change password

y esto para cada uno de los usuarios

[mucho ojo] > para el usuario pma asígnale todos los privilegios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TE EMPEZARAN A SALIR ERRORES DE AUTENTICACIÓN IGNÓRELOS (SON ERRORES POR QUE NO TE HAS LOGIADO)

Una vez pasas al archivo config.inc.php e configúralo de  la siguiente manera

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '<contraseña>'; 

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '<contraseña>';


$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma_savedsearches';


/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

listo al volver si te quitara ese anuncio y has configurado en la forma más cansilla phpmyadmin

[DEBES REINICIAR EL SERVIDOR]

Answer (score 1):

Debes editar el fichero `config.inc` que esta en `xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc`

Y añadir las siguientes líneas antes del comentario `/* End of servers configuration*/::`

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma_savedsearches';
```

Comment: Hice lo sugerido pero el problema persiste. Alguna otra opción? (La tabla phpmyadmin ya estaba creada cuando actualicé la version de phpmyadmin (ver screen)
[![imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdS14.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdS14.png)